# PL/I copybook to COBOL copybook

Tags: cobol, mainframe, copybook, pl-i

How to convert PL/I copybook to COBOL copybook.

```
2 PL_COPYBOOK.
  3 FIRST_FIELD   CHAR(20).
  3 SECOND_FIELD  FIXED(5).
  3 THIRD_FIELD   FIXED(9,0).
  3 FOURTH_FIELD  FIXED(7,1).
  3 FIFTH_FIELD   BIT(8).
  3 SIXTH_FIELD   FIXED BIN(15).
```

Comment: Where is level 1 ?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest looking each data item definition up in the PL/I documentation for the compiler you are using and translate that into the equivalent COBOL data item definition.

For example, FIRST_FIELD would be PIC X(20).

You will need to pay attention to details such as whether or not slack bytes are introduced in your data structure for alignment purposes.

Comment: Upvoted especially for mentioning alignment. It is iportant to note that by default PL/I stuctures are ALIGNED while COBOL structures are not. With the question's copybook it is important how the level 1 item is defined - if it's not defined as UNALIGNED there will be a padding byte before SIXTH_FIELD which has to be accounted for in COBOL (e.g. by using SYNCHRONIZED).

Comment: Is there any open source tool available to perform this conversion.

Comment: @Mohit I am aware of no open source tools to perform this sort of conversion.

Comment: I think it depends on the compiler version, but PL/I can work with pic as @cschneid said, then the transformation is easy!